# Limit of an average integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Lebesgue's differentiation theorem states that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is locally summable then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{|B(x_0,r)|}\int_{B(x_0,r)}f(x)\,dx\rightarrow f(x_0),
\end{align*}
as $r\rightarrow 0$.

It is also apparently true that for continuous $f$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{|\partial B(x_0,r)|}\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)}f(y)dS(y)\rightarrow f(x_0).
\end{align*}

I was wondering why the second integral is true? Is this a famous result or is the proof really obvious?

Thanks alot!

Comment: What do you mean by $|B(x_0,r)|$ or $|\partial B(x_0,r)|$ ?

Comment: the volume and surface area of a ball of radius r centred at $x_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first limit holds for almost all $x_0$.

The second limit need not be true for almost all $x_0$. With $n=1$, let $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is irrational and $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational. Take $x_0$ irrational. Then there are arbitrarily small $r$ such that $x_0-r$ and $x_0+r$ are rational, and then
$$
\int_{\partial B(x_0,r)} f(y) dS(y) = 0.
$$
However, for most other $r$ the integral above is 2.

**Stuff added later:** If $f$ is continuous and $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x-x_0| < \delta$. If $r< \delta$ we then have
$$
\biggl| \frac{1}{|\partial B(x_0,r)|} \int_{\partial B (x_0,r)} f(y) dS(y) - f(x_0) \biggr| < \varepsilon
$$
and the result follows.

Comment: Sorry - let the integrand be continuous

Comment: Then it is true! For small $r$, the values of $f$ on the ball are almost the same as $f(x_0)$ and the result follows.

Comment: If $x$ is irrational, then **no** $r$ fulfils that $x+r$ and $x-r$ are rational. Otherwise, $2x=(x-r)+(x+r)$ would be rational and so would $x$.

Comment: That is true, but (exactly) one of $x-r$ and $x+r$ can be rational, and that is sufficient for the example.

Comment: @Tomas: Thanks for the clarification, let me think about that for a moment. Meanwhile: Interestingly, the claim is true for $n \geq 3$ and $f\in L^p$ with $p > n/(n-1)$, as a consequence of Stein's spherical maximal theorem, see https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/steins-spherical-maximal-theorem/.

Comment: Thanks PhoemueX for the information. That is indeed interesting, and I was not aware of it.

Comment: Concluding remark: The modified statement is indeed true. There is certainly a nullsequence with $x+t_n \in \Bbb{Q}$ (and then $x-t_n \notin \Bbb{Q}$). On the other hand, if $x\pm \in \Bbb{Q}$, this forces $t$ to lie in a countable set, hence $x\pm \notin \Bbb{Q}$ (for both signs simultaneously) for most values of $t$.